# Python list forward fill elements according to thresholds

Tags: python, list, fill, forward

I have a list

```
a = ["Today, 30 Dec",
     "01:10",
     "02:30",
     "Tomorrow, 31 Dec", 
     "00:00",
     "04:30",
     "05:30",
     "01 Jan 2023",
     "01:00",
     "10:00"]
```

and would like to kind of forward fill this list so that the result looks like this

```
b = ["Today, 30 Dec 01:10",
     "Today, 30 Dec 02:30",
     "Tomorrow, 31 Dec 00:00",
     "Tomorrow, 31 Dec 04:30",
     "Tomorrow, 31 Dec 05:30",
     "01 Jan 2023 01:00",
     "01 Jan 2023 10:00"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I iterate over the list and check if it is a time with regex. If it isn't I save it, to prepend it to the following items, and the append it to the output.

Code:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint


def forward(input_list):
    output = []
    for item in input_list:
        if not re.fullmatch(r"\d\d:\d\d", item):
            forwarded = item
        else:
            output.append(f"{forwarded} {item}")
    return output


a = ["Today, 30 Dec",
     "01:10",
     "02:30",
     "Tomorrow, 31 Dec",
     "00:00",
     "04:30",
     "05:30",
     "01 Jan 2023",
     "01:00",
     "10:00"]

b = forward(a)
pprint(b)
```

Output:

```
['Today, 30 Dec 01:10',
 'Today, 30 Dec 02:30',
 'Tomorrow, 31 Dec 00:00',
 'Tomorrow, 31 Dec 04:30',
 'Tomorrow, 31 Dec 05:30',
 '01 Jan 2023 01:00',
 '01 Jan 2023 10:00']
```

Comment: You're very generous for writing this person's program for them.  But on this site we generally try not to do that; we prefer that the person write it themselves, with a little help from us, so that they _learn_.

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for the input, I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that list contains *dates* and *times*.

Any item that contains a space is a date value; otherwise it is a time value.

Iterate over the list.  If you see a date value, save it as the current date.  If you see a time value, append it to the current date and save that value the new list.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    a = ["Today, 30 Dec",
         "01:10",
         "02:30",
         "Tomorrow, 31 Dec",
         "00:00",
         "04:30",
         "05:30",
         "01 Jan 2023",
         "01:00",
         "10:00"]

    b = []

    base = ""
    for x in a:
        if ":" in x:
            b.append(base + " " + x)
        else:
            base = x

    print(b)
```

simply iterate over your data and store the front string and if the current element contains a colon append it

Output:

```
['Today, 30 Dec 01:10', 
'Today, 30 Dec 02:30', 
'Tomorrow, 31 Dec 00:00', 
'Tomorrow, 31 Dec 04:30', 
'Tomorrow, 31 Dec 05:30', 
'01 Jan 2023 01:00', 
'01 Jan 2023 10:00']
```